# A property for maps between metric spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, isometric-immersion

Let $X, Y$ be metric spaces with distance functions denoted by $d_X, d_Y$ respectively. Consider a map $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$. I am interested in the following property: for every $x,y,z \in X$, if $d_X(x,y) \leq d_X(x,z)$ then $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) \leq d_Y(f(x), f(z))$. My question is: is this property known and studied? If yes, could you elaborate on the terminology and give references for it? How is it related to $f$ being an isometry?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Note that this means preserving the 3-ary relation $R(x,y,z)$ defined by "$d(x,y)\le d(x,z)$". A metric space can be characterized by a countable number of binary relations (namely the relations $d(x,y)\le r$ for $r$ ranging over rationals), but not, as far as I know, a single relation.

Comment: One can wonder which 3-ary relations $R$ arise in this way from a metric space. Obvious conditions: are $R(x,x,y)$, $R(x,y,y)$ hold for all $x,y$, transitivity of the binary relation $R(x,-,-)$ for each $x$, and $R(x,y,x)$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: In the case $X=Y=\mathbb R$, this property is "$f$ is monotone", isn't it?

Comment: @PietroMajer no, it's much stronger. It indeed implies monotone, say, non-decreasing (up to compose with $x\mapsto -x$). Taking $t>0$, $y=x-t$ and $z=x+t$ and then exchanging $y$ and $z$ shows $f(x+t)-f(x)=f(x)-f(x-t)$. By continuity, this seems to force $f$ to be affine. I.e., in this case, we have only similarities (considering constant as $0$-similarities).

Comment: I think this argument can be generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed, if $f: \ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ has this property, then it has to preserve circumcenters of simplices. By this I mean that if $c$ is the circumencter of a (non-degenerate) simplex with vertices $v_1, ..., v_{n+1}$, then $f(c)$ is the circumcenter of the simplex with vertices $f(v_1), ..., f(v_{n+1})$. Does this imply that $f$ is affine?

Comment: So in general such an $f:X\to Y$ maps any sphere $\{y\in X: d(x,y)=r\}$ of $X$  to a sphere of $Y$ centered at $f(x)$.

Comment: Suppose $X$ is “connected by folding rules”, meaning that for any $r>0$ and $x,x’$ in $X$ there are $x=x_0,x_1,\dots, x_m=x’$ such that  $d(x_i,x_{i+1})=r$ (this is the case of any normed space $X$). Then since such an $f$  maps isosceles triangles to isosceles triangles, it also verifies $d(f(x),f(y))=\phi(d(x,y))$ for some increasing function $\phi$ (and subadditive, at least for the case of $X$ a normed space).

Comment: @gm01 In the case $n = 2$ and if $f$ is assumed to be onto this implies that any $3$ points sitting on the line will end up mapping into the same line. Which implies $\phi(x/2) = \phi(x)/2$ in Pietro's terms.

Comment: More generally, for $f:R^n \rightarrow R^n$ surjective. Any $3$ points sitting on the line(= not sitting on any shere) will end up mapping into the same line(= not on any sphere). Thus, $\phi(x/2) = \phi(x)/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" How is it related to $f$ being an isometry?"

Obviously, any isometry $f$ has the property in question.

On the other hand, not every $f$ having this property is an isometry. Indeed, let $X=Y=\{1,2,3\}$ with $d_X(x,x)=d_Y(x,x)=0$ for $x\in X$, and with $d_X(x,y)=x+y$ and $d_Y(x,y)=1$ for distinct $x$ and $y$ in $X$. Then the identity map from $X$ to $Y=X$ has the property in question but is not an isometry. $\quad\Box$

Comment: There are so many trivial examples of non-isometries with this property that I expect OP to be aware of them.

Comment: @YCor : On the other hand, do you know what else can be said about this particular property  -- especially concerning its relation with being an isometry?

Comment: I don't really know, OP's question is quite open-ended.

Comment: @YCor : Why do you think the question " How is it related to $f$ being an isometry?" is quite open-ended? What kinds of relations can there be, in principle, between two properties? The only such relations that I can see are implications: that one of the properties implies (or does not imply) the other one. If the OP knew such relations, they should have been mentioned in the OP -- but then what would be the point of question "How is it related to $f$ being an isometry?"? So, I fail to see the point of your first comment to my question.

Comment: In this interpretation, the question is highly off-topic: examples of non-isometries already occur between two 2-point metric spaces. When I say open-ended, I mean, for instance that when some condition are given on $X$ and $Y$, the question of determining such maps might become more interesting. E.g., what are spaces $X$ for which the only $f:X\to X$ with the condition are similarities (i.e., multiply the distance by a constant)? What about Euclidean spaces?

Comment: @YCor : If you would introduce (say $k$) properties in addition to the two properties in question, then you would be talking about relations between $k+2$ properties rather than between the original two properties. I think everyone is free to entertain such a modification of the literal reading of the question, but it is hardly reasonable to insist on that, as it now seems to be the case with your first comment to my question.

Comment: My general point is that off-topic questions are not worth answers. Your interpretation of the question is perfectly reasonable and this was the first I understood — and it is confirmed by the fact your answer is accepted. In a sense, I'm disappointed that a potentially interesting question is "settled" by a trivial remark.

Comment: @YCor : Then, I think, this is what you should have said right away. And then you could also have posted what you thought would be a potentially interesting modification of the question. I am actually curious: What could such a modification be?

Comment: A modification could be: just the same question, but mentioning the most trivial examples. Of course this makes the question quite open-ended. A specific follow-up question: what are spaces for which every self-map $f$ preserving this ternary relation is a similarity (i.e. multiplies the distance by a scalar)? Etc.

Comment: @YCor : To me, this follow-up question seems to be a bit too far from the OP to be called a modification.

Comment: Exactly, this is why I called it a follow-up question, and not a modification.

Comment: @YCor : However, my question was "What could such a modification be?".

Comment: My answer is then: none that I could have decided myself in the name of the OP. In any case the answer is accepted, so this discussion is now pointless.

Comment: @YCor : I am glad that, apparently, we have eventually agreed that there appears to be no reasonable way to interpret the original question other than literally or to modify it in a reasonable way. Of course, this takes us back to what was the point of your first (rather aggressively stated) comment in this thread (and I hope we can now avoid going around in circles). Simply speaking, I think all this thread should be removed. If you remove all your comments in this thread, I will remove all my comments here.

Comment: Yes, but I think that the question should be closed as off-topic and I'm not sure we agree on this. My main regret is not to have commented from the beginning something such as *"There are trivial examples of non-isometries with this property (e.g. constant maps), and even non-similarities. Could you make the question a little more specific, or at least explain what are your thoughts so far?"*

Comment: @YCor : I think such a comment (which of course you are completely free to make now or at any other time) would have discouraged users (myself included) to some degree from answering this question. On the other hand, I have seen many questions of the same level of difficulty on MO left alone and sometimes generously upvoted, and recently I saw an answer (very generously upvoted), whose main idea was to use (non-rigorously) the approximation $e^x\approx1+x$ for small $x$. So, can we remove this thread (and then you could comment on the degree of difficulty of the question)?

Answer (score 3):

Under mild conditions on the metric space $(X,d)$, we can assure that either $f$ is constant or $f$ is injective, so $f$ is either trivial or behaves similar to an isometry. Let $\simeq$ be the equivalence relation on $X$ where we set $x\simeq y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$. Let $U$ be an equivalence class of $\simeq$, and suppose that $U$ has more than one point. Let $r_U$ be the supremum of all real numbers $r$ such that for each $x\in U$, there exists some $y\in U$ with $d(x,y)\geq r$.

Proposition: $r_A\geq\text{Diam}(A)/2$ for any set $A$ with metric $d$.

Proof: Suppose that $s<\text{Diam}(A)$. Then there are $u,v\in A$ with $d(u,v)>s$. If $x\in A$, then $d(x,u)>s/2$ or $d(x,v)>s/2$, since if $d(x,u)\leq s/2,d(x,v)\leq s/2$, then $d(u,v)\leq s$ by the triangle inequality. Q.E.D.

In particular, $r_U>0$.

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then we say that a subset $C\subseteq X$ is $\epsilon$-uniformly clopen if whenever $x\in C$, we have $B_\epsilon(x)\subseteq C$.

Observation: If $C\subseteq X$, then $C\subseteq X$ is $\epsilon$-uniformly clopen if and only if $C^c$ is $\epsilon$-uniformly clopen.

Proof: $C\subseteq X$ is $\epsilon$-uniformly clopen iff
$\forall x,y\in X,d(x,y)<\epsilon\rightarrow(x\in C\rightarrow y\in C)$ iff
$\forall x,y\in X,d(x,y)<\epsilon\rightarrow(y\in C^c\rightarrow x\in C^c)$ iff
$C^c$ is $\epsilon$-uniformly clopen.

Q.E.D.

In particular, every $\epsilon$-uniformly clopen set is clopen. We say that a subset of a metric space is uniformly clopen if it is $\epsilon$-uniformly clopen for some $\epsilon>0$. We say that a metric space is uniformly connected if the only uniformly clopen sets are the empty set and the entire space.

Observation: The set $U$ is $r_U$-uniformly clopen.

Proof: Suppose that $x\in U$ and $d(x,y)\leq r_U$. Then there is some $z\in U$ with
$d(x,z)\geq r_U$. Therefore, $d(f(x),f(y))\leq d(f(x),f(z))=0$ since $x\simeq z$. Therefore, $f(x)=f(y)$, so $y\in U$ as well. Q.E.D.

Therefore, if $(X,d)$ is uniformly connected and $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)\Rightarrow d(f(x),f(y))\leq d(f(x),f(z))$, then either $f$ is injective or $f$ is constant.

Comment: The terminology "uniformly connected" might be misleading because it is weaker than connected. Maybe "metrically connected"? Examples of metrically connected spaces are dense subsets of connected spaces.

Comment: The term 'uniformly connected' has already been established, and it is the analogue of connectedness for uniform spaces. A uniform space $X$ is uniformly connected iff the only uniformly continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ are the constant functions.

Comment: OK, fine. I'd like to know who coined this terminology... Wikipedia quotes Cantor 1883, I doubt it...